# To get a table in drupal 7 same as content_type_[your_field_name] in drupal 6?

Tags: 7

In the **Drupal 6** database, for every content type, there is a  table that's called **content_type_[your_field_name]** 
Now I have a database query as follows in drupal 6 :

```
db_query("SELECT n.nid FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {content_type_field_abc} s ON n.vid = s.vid                                                                       
                          INNER JOIN {def_table} sts ON s.nid = sts.nid                                                                                                    
                          WHERE n.type = 'trans' AND s.field_study = '%s' AND sts.status = 1", $account->name);
```

Then how can I use db_query in **drupal 7** to get **a table containing all the fields of the content type as columns** same as drupal 6 ?

Or 
Simply, how can I write the **above given query** in drupal 7 ?

Answer (score 1):

That depends what fields you have defined in your content type.

An easier way is to load the node object and fetch your data from it.

`$node = node_load($nid);`

If you install the [Devel](http://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module you can do `dpm($node);` and find how to access all data attached to your node.

Comment: I am porting my site from drupal 6 to drupal 7 so I just wanted something which would work the same as above query.How can I add the data from the node_load to database as seen in the query above ?